# Netbeans y github nbproject

Tags: netbeans, github

Tengo una duda si yo excluyo la carpeta nbproject en git este ya no se carga pero el punto es que si alguien mas baja mi repositorio el proyecto ya no les funciona porque netbeans no lo reconoce como si fuera un proyecto de este . alguna idea sugerencia o recomendación de como manejar netbeans con git ?

Comment: No lo entiendo... ¿cuál es el problema con subir el nbproject a git? Ciertamente hay formas más elegantes (Maven, etc.) pero si es lo que usas...

Comment: como lo mencione subo un proyecto de netbeans a github .. como podras entender netbeans genera una carpeta con nbproject donde mete sus archivos en la practica se dice que no se debe subir el nbproject .. si yo lo excluyo esta excelente pero si alguien mas descarga mi proyecto el ya no lo podra abrir con netbeans porque no existe estos archivos .. entonces estos archivos se suben o no se suben

Comment: Si lo que has creado es un proyecto Java sin maven o gradle si tendrás que subir la carpeta nbproject, por eso existen opciones como Maven que abstraen la construcción del proyecto para que cualquier IDE pueda entenderlo y de esa forma es mas fácil versionar el código en github.